# Artifactory -SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException Issue when importing v6 repositories into v7 instance

Tags: migration, artifactory

I didn't find any answer to this issue we had during our artifactory migration, so here our issue , investigation and resolution :
The goal was to upgrade our artifactory server 6.20.1 to 7.49.8 on another server using export system / import system procedure upgrade.

We manage to import all configuration except some of repositories that were reported empty.
We tried to export / import them manually using repository export / import fonctionnality, but an exception raised :

```
     Error occurred during import: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ARTIFACTORY_XX"."WATCHES"."USERNAME")
```

Investigation :
We compared repository contents between the 2 versions (as we had 2 running versions) and we found that 12 repositories upon 119 were empty and those ones whe the only one with users configured as watchers (either in repository root or in sub folders).
Inspecting export folder we found that those repositories had watchers.xml files with some content :

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <watchers>
      <watchers class="linked-hash-set">
        <watcher>
          <username>John</username>
          <watchingSinceTime>1679923685543</watchingSinceTime>
        </watcher>
      </watchers>
    </watchers>
```

we exported another repository from our v7 instance with "followers" and we saw that watchers.xml file was different in v7 :

```
    <watchers>
        <watchers>
            <username>s0130928</username>
            <watchingSinceTime>1698133067209</watchingSinceTime>
        </watchers>
    </watchers>
```

Resolution:
Modifying the original watchers.xml files from export to match v7 format or removing all watchers.xml files resolved our import issue.